# What is the proper way to use flyway environment variables in gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, flyway

At the moment, I have 2 databases, one is local and dev, However, I configured the local one okay using config files and a specific gradle task, this runs okay;

However since Im trying to simulate what would happen in my pipeline, how can I set it up so that reads from the environment variables on my machine, so far this is what I expected;

I checked the environment variable by running

```
echo $FLYWAY_URL
```

This returned

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

Which means variable exists, Next I setup my task like this in gradle;

```
def jdbcDevUrl = System.getenv()['FLYWAY_URL']

task migrateDev(type: FlywayMigrateTask) {
    url = jdbcDevUrl
    user = 'myUsr2'
    password = 'mySecretPwd2'
    locations = ['filesystem:doc/flyway/migrations']
}
```

However this does not work at all. I have tried to run by not setting up [url properties from here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/) hoping it would be picked up automatically but it does not work.

Also using a config file with

```
flyway.url=${FLYWAY_URL}
```

does not work. Im using community edition.

All I get is

```
Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!